# PHP syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING

Tags: php, variables, syntax-error

Following code gives me the error.

```
    <?php
echo "<a href='prefs.php?username=$PHP_USER'>$lang_menu["prefs"]</a>";
?>
```

I'm pretty sure it has something to do with me requesting 2 php variables, no idea how to solve.

Comment: `echo "<a href='prefs.php?username={$PHP_USER}'>{$lang_menu["prefs"]}</a>";`

Comment: I see too many questions like this. Take the time to learn how to [interpret errors and fix your code](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2013/05/fixing-php-errors/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, you cannot write unescaped double quotes in a double-quoted string. And I'd advise against writing unescaped text into HTML and URLs. Try this:

```
<?php
echo '<a href="prefs.php?username=' . rawurlencode($PHP_USER) . '">' . htmlspecialchars($lang_menu["prefs"]) . '</a>';
?>
```

**Edit:** A couple of clarifications...

1. These are valid strings:

   ```
   $foo = "Hello, World!";
   $foo = "Hello, 'World!'";
   $foo = "Hello, \"World!\"";
   ```

   This is *not*:

   ```
   $foo = "Hello, "World!"";
   ```
2. SQL injection, as the word suggests, refers to the database query language called SQL. This code does not contain SQL and it does not interact at all with any database.

So it's nothing about dots or SQL injection. It's about certain characters that have a special meaning in certain semantic contexts. It's about [text within text](http://kunststube.net/escapism/).

Comment: So I was just basicly missing the dots? I assume use the extra functions to prevent SQL injections?

Comment: Why would you use rawurlencode and htmlspecialchar then? nvm just read the developer docs. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Replace with

```
<?php 

echo "<a href='prefs.php?username=".$PHP_USER."'>".$lang_menu['prefs']."</a>";

?>
```

Comment: If you use single quotes to contain strings you can still use double quotes for html attributes.

Comment: I don't see why we should insist on using double quotes on html attributes. It's not going to have an effect our code that I am aware of.

Comment: No but it's fairly standard - plus when you use double quotes PHP looks for variables and {} to parse which is an unnecessary (though very small) overhead. My point is basically, why change from the standard double quotes, when there's just no need

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know it before. +1 in your comment for this advice.

Answer (score 1):

`$variables` splitted with quotes `"` :

```
echo "<a href='prefs.php?username=".$PHP_USER."'>".$lang_menu['prefs']."</a>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
<?php
echo "<a href=\"prefs.php?username=".$PHP_USER."\" >".$lang_menu["prefs"]."</a>";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?php
 echo "<a href='prefs.php?username=".$PHP_USER."'>".$lang_menu['prefs']."</a>";
?>
```